# User control of Keydown Event, combination of three keys windows form c#

Tags: c#, user-controls

Hello I hope you can help me.
I have a user control that has the ProcessCmdKey method overridden and it works fine for one key, but the need arose to combine three keys and I don't know how to do it since the current method only reads the first key that is pressed.
thanks for your valuable help

Comment: Which keys might that be?